# JavaPlay put routes file in subdirectory

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to make reference from Java Play's [routes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaRouting) file to another route file that is in a separate directory?

(assuming Play 2.8.x)

For example, consider the content of `conf/routes`

```
->      /admin                       FIXME
```

I need the `FIXME` placholder to reference the `admin.routes` file inside `conf/routes-dir/admin.routes`

---

As far as I know, the only option is to move `admin.routes` to `conf/` directory. Then, `routes` file would look like this

```
->      /admin                       admin.Routes
```

However, I want to keep all routes files inside separate directory

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom directory with routs files to config

build.sbt

```scala
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += "./customDir/"
```

or

```scala
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "customDir"
```

If you need add routes from inner conf folder, you must use

```scala
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "conf" / "routes_v2"
```

for checking results you can use this for print results to console

```scala
Compile / routes := {
  val value = (Compile / routes).value
  System.out.print("Compile / routes: " + value)
  value
}
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories := {
  val value = (Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories).value
  System.out.print("Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories: " + value)
  value
}
```

[in Sbt documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+resource+directory)

### Update ATTENTION

Please use multi-module for this, because you will take a problem with RevercRoutes generation (will be generated only from one routes file)
[MORE information about splitting route file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/sbtSubProjects#Splitting-the-route-file)

Comment: Both examples you mentioned do not work. First one with `No Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], String] found, so String cannot be appended to Seq[java.io.File]`. Second one with 
  `unmanagedResourceDirectories from unmanagedResourceDirectories (/home/project/build.sbt:9)
     Did you mean Web-assets / unmanagedResourceDirectories ?`

Comment: Adding `Compile /` prefix to second one conflicts with the `Assets`: `value Assets is not a member of object controllers.routes
[error]         <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">`. Adding it to the first one produces `error: No Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], String] found, so String cannot be appended to Seq[java.io.File]`

Comment: this example from documentation from my link:
`Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "extra-resources"`
and you can use file('<path_string>') for getting file instance from path string

Comment: @Talos, thank you for your remark on the answer, please read more info from documentation link. If you need more help, please make short-sample in gitHub, then i will can help you

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/TaIos/java-play-toy-project) is a complete example that illustrates my point in the question. Just run `sbt run`. Lines that cause the problem are annotated with `FIXME`.

Comment: You make a mistake, you lost  `conf` in path
Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / "conf" / "routes_v2"

Comment: @Talos, am updated my main answer, please read it

Comment: There is still a problem and I think this is impossible to achieve with the Java Play + SBT – having routes file in a `conf` directory of a main project, as described in my original answer (updated the complete example on GH).

Comment: @Talos, please read part of my answer *Update ATTENTION*. you can use this way with multi-module